# Linking to specific jquery tab from external page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jquery script called Feature List for displaying different sections of info on a page.  The user can click through the various tabs to see different content.  It works great for what I want it to do but I was hoping to be able to link to each tab from an external page.  The problem is I'm not great with jquery am not sure how to go about this or if it's possible with the way the page is set up.

You can see the page and view the source at http://nourishedbynature.co.uk/

Ideally I'd like to be able to link to the page and display a specific tab by appending something the the url.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use a hash fragment (like `mysite.com/#tab2`) and check it on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Use document.location.hash on $.ready then fire the jQuery code that corresponds to that hash.

```
$.ready(function(){
    gotosectionforhash(document.location.hash);
});
```